# Can not use full-text search in user instance SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, ssms

It is really strange in SSMS, I have installed and confirmed twice that Full-Text search is installed, and it is up and running but while creating FullTextCatalog I get the same error again and again.

Version :
**Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0**

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FullTextCatalog 
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [FullTextCatalog] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
```

ERROR:

> Msg 9982, Level 16, State 100, Line 5
> Cannot use full-text search in user instance.
> Completion time: 2022-09-21T13:34:10.2052908+05:30

[image: original image]

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server is it? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73797348/edit) your question to include the output of `SELECT @@VERSION`. Not all versions and editions support Full-text and semantic search.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for responding.

Version : Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0

Answer (score 0):

LocalDb is a user instance server meaning it starts on demand and does not run constantly.  Because of this, it is not able to support a full text catalog.

If you need full text catalog, you need to install a persistent server of Sql Server Express.  You can download it here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads.